# Oracle SQL: Using CASE in a SELECT statement with Substr

Tags: sql, oracle

In a `SELECT` statement would it be possible to evaluate a `Substr` using CASE? Or what would be the best way to return a `sub string` based on a condition?

I am trying to retrieve a name from an event description column of a table. The string in the event description column is formatted either like `text text (Mike Smith) text text` or `text text (Joe Schmit (Manager)) text text`. I would like to return the name only, but having some of the names followed by `(Manager)` is throwing off my `SELECT` statement.

This is my `SELECT` statement:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (
 SELECT Substr(Substr(eventdes,Instr(eventdes,'(')+1),1,
    Instr(eventdes,')') - Instr(eventdes,'(')-1)
   FROM mytable
      WHERE admintype = 'admin'
    AND entrytime BETWEEN sysdate - (5/(24*60)) AND sysdate
    AND eventdes LIKE '%action taken by%'
     ORDER BY id DESC
     )
 WHERE ROWNUM <=1
```

This returns things like `Mike Smith` if there is no `(Manager)`, but returns things like `Joe Schmit (Manager` if there is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the "John Doe" sample in your second paragraph, are the square brackets supposed to be there?

Comment: No, they were to signify what may or may not be in the field. I edited my post to make that more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0278b9/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE ( id, admintype, entrytime, eventdes ) AS
SELECT 1, 'admin', SYSDATE, 'action taken by (John Doe (Manager)) more text' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( eventdes, '\((.*?)(\s*\(.*?\))?\)', 1, 1, 'i', 1 )
       FROM   mytable
       WHERE  admintype = 'admin'
       AND    entrytime BETWEEN sysdate - (5/(24*60)) AND sysdate
       AND    eventdes LIKE '%action taken by%'
       ORDER BY id DESC
     )
WHERE ROWNUM <=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0278b9/1/0)**:

```
| REGEXP_SUBSTR(EVENTDES,'\((.*?)(\S*\(.*?\))?\)',1,1,'I',1) |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                   John Doe |
```

**Edit:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1b00/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE ( id, admintype, entrytime, eventdes ) AS
SELECT 1, 'admin', SYSDATE, 'action taken by (Doe, John (Manager)) more text' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( Name, INSTR( Name, ',' ) + 1 ) || ' ' || SUBSTR( Name, 1, INSTR( Name, ',' ) - 1 ) AS Full_Name,
       REGEXP_REPLACE( Name, '^(.*?),\s*(.*)$', '\2 \1' ) AS Full_Name2
FROM ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( eventdes, '\((.*?)(\s*\(.*?\))?\)', 1, 1, 'i', 1 ) AS Name
       FROM   mytable
       WHERE  admintype = 'admin'
--       AND    entrytime BETWEEN sysdate - (5/(24*60)) AND sysdate
       AND    eventdes LIKE '%action taken by%'
       ORDER BY id DESC
     )
WHERE ROWNUM <=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1b00/10/0)**:

```
| FULL_NAME | FULL_NAME2 |
|-----------|------------|
|  John Doe |   John Doe |
```

Comment: If you don't mind, what would your approach be if all of the names were listed with the last name first and no comma after the last name, and you wanted to flip them so the first name was listed first?

Comment: @Walter41 Added an edit with two different solutions. If you will always have the comma then I'd use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` (as its probably more performant) but if the comma format is optional then `REGEXP_REPLACE` might be better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use INSTR to search the last ')', but I would prefer a Regular Expression.

This extracts everything between the first '(' and the last ')' and the TRIMs remove the brackets (Oracle doesn't support look around in RegEx):

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(eventdes, '\(.*\)'), '('), ')')
```

Comment: This would return "John Doe [(Manager)]" from the first example string.  What he wants is just "John Doe" (as I read the question).

Comment: Or it would return "John Doe (Manager" if the square brackets aren't meant to be there (which is unclear from the rest of the question).

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a regex that would do this without a replace but I am not smart enough to work it out so I combined a REGEXP_SUBSTRING that replaces your multiple instr methods and a REGEXP_REPLACE to replace the ' (MANAGER)' portion is it exists.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(eventdes, '\((.*)\)', 1, 1, 'i', 1), ' \(MANAGER\)', '')
    FROM mytable
    WHERE admintype = 'admin'
    AND entrytime BETWEEN sysdate - (5/(24*60)) AND sysdate
    AND eventdes LIKE '%action taken by%'
    ORDER BY id DESC
 )
WHERE ROWNUM <=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different take on the problem.  This regexp starts at the position of the first open paren + 1 (the first letter of the name), then returns the first group from that point in the string on that consists of 1 or more characters that is not a close paren or an open paren. The TRIM gets rid of the trailing space if there is a manager.

```
SQL> with tbl(id, admintype, entrytime, eventdes ) AS
  2  ( SELECT 1, 'admin', SYSDATE, 'action taken by (John Doe (Manager)) more text' FROM DUAL
  3    union
  4    SELECT 1, 'admin', SYSDATE, 'action taken by (Jane Doe) more text' FROM DUAL
  5  )
  6  select trim(regexp_substr(eventdes, '([^\)\(]+)', instr(eventdes, '(')+1, 1)) name
  7  from tbl;

NAME
----------------------------------------------
Jane Doe
John Doe

SQL>
```